# DLRs are queued at SMPP Kannel

Tags: smpp, kannel

I just want to know what are specific reasons where in DLRs are being queued in SMPP Kannel? Or are being rejected.

Set up of SMS flow: Client SMPP -> SMPP -> HTTP -> HTTP partner -> End user

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Queued DLR can mean a few things, 2 of them are seemingly the most common.

The first reason is that you never received a DLR from your SMSC. The could mean the message got lost somewhere, or the end carrier/middle hop does not support DLR. The DLR will "queue" on your platform until it receives the DLR or timeouts.

The second reason is you are not receiving a "Final" DLR, rather you are receiving an intermediary DLR. You may be getting back a type 4 (queued/buffered) DLR. With some SMSCs this is the closest "final" DLR type you will get back since carriers often do not report on successful/unsuccessful delivery to the actual handset, instead they acknowledge with a type=4 DLR that they received the message, and will attempt delivery.

Kannel is waiting for a DLR or type 1 or 2 (final) until clearing the DLR out of the queue. It would look something like this in your bearerbox.log.

```
DLR[internal]: Looking for DLR smsc=test, ts=<>, dst=<>, type=4
DLR[internal]: created DLR message for URL <>
DLR[internal]: DLR not destroyed, still waiting for other delivery report
```

Unfortunately, if the second reason turns out to your problem you will probably need to modify the Kannel source code because to my knowledge you can not force Kannel to remove a type=4 DLR from the queue.

Hope this helps.